# Trying to multiply a 2d tensor by a 1d tensor, starting from a specific column in the 2d tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Say I have a two dimensional tenor like

```
r = tf.constant([[0],[1]])
```

and a two dimensional tensor like

```
v = tf.constant([[1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 2],[5, 3, 5, 4, 7, 2]])
```

I would like to be able to update v, by multiplying r from a specific column? for example if from column 2 (zero-based), the resulting tensor would be [[1, 3, 5, 0, 0, 0],[5, 3, 5, 4, 7, 2]]

Any solution I come up with results in the below error

```
v[:, 2:] *= r[:, None]

TypeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: the example of the first tensor is two-dimensional, not one dimensional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do in two steps:

```
res = v[:, 2:] * r
res = tf.concat((v[:, :2], res), axis=-1)
```

Comment: This was a huge help Andrey and is much appreciated